# Linkedin API auto update after allowing access

Tags: php, api, oauth, linkedin-api

Once the user allows access to the LinkedIn Application how to auto update the user profile without showing the allow access page to the user again 
should I store oauth access token somewhere in database & can I use that token for auto update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to store the credentials, and can use it for some specified period of time after that you need to either refresh the token or you can ask for another token.

Comment: currently m getting https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=78--b235d495-0e12-xxxx so after allow access where to use the access_token parameter to get the data directly

Comment: Actually I implemented [scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java)  for Facebook and Google , Linkedin would be my next target , so what I did after getting access_token object I save that object in my database and by exchanging that object I can access the data on either Facebook or google, hoping the same for the Linkedin

Comment: $linkedin->request_token    =   unserialize($_SESSION['requestToken']);
$linkedin->oauth_verifier   =   $_SESSION['oauth_verifier'];
$linkedin->access_token     =   unserialize($_SESSION['oauth_access_token']);

can i replace oauth_access_token with the one i will store in db will it work

Comment: No luck on that tried modifying the access_token with one in the url still is pop ups an error of 401 any ideas how to get this solved?